# Libs from outside tsconfig directory - How to configure?

Tags: angular, typescript, tsconfig

I'm making angular 4 app. I have folder with my `jsLibs` that is outside app directory. I have to configure `tsconfig.json` to make it work.

Here is my clean `tsconfig.json` after `angular-cli`'s generation:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm adding to `compilerOptions`:

```
"rootDirs": [
  "src",
  "../../../libsNg/schemater/src/app/schemater"
],
```

And import `import {SchematerModule} from "./schemater.module";` is still not working.

In `src/app/schemater` is `schemater.module.ts` file.

How to configure it?

Comment: How are you exporting your `schemater.module.ts`?

Comment: `@NgModule({...}) export class SchematerModule {}` All is working when I put whole directory inside `app/` folder